# Vercel deployment with django

Tags: python, django, deployment, runtime, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my django app on Vercel but it isn't working, this is my vercel.json code:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "functions": {
        "core/wsgi.py": {
            "runtime": "vercel-python@9.8.1"
        },
        "build_files.sh": {
            "runtime": "@vercel/static-build"
        }
    },
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/static/(.*)",
            "dest": "/static/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "core/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's raising this error:

Error: Function Runtimes must have a valid version, for example now-php@1.0.0.

Can someone help me? Please